# CSS: increase width for list items

Tags: css

I am new to css and am currently trying to split the screen in two parts and place text on the left and the right side. However, for some reason the right "box" doesn't cover the whole right part of the screen, only like 200-300 px...

JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/19mw8hzL/

The black text should reach to the right side of the screen.

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="one">
    <p class="w-text-1">Strategy</p>
  </div>
  <div id="two">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Visioning</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Strategic Analysis</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Strategy Formulation</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Business Model Innovation</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Financial Modeling</a></li>
     </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Based on the css in your linked example, I guess the lines `#two li:nth-child(4):before {display: block; content: '';}` are responsible for wrapping your text therefore not taking the full width. Removing it, and assigning a width to the container might solve this issue... assuming you meant left to right (and not top to bottom).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flexbox can do that.

```css
.w-text-1 {
  font-family: 'Garamond', serif;
  color: rgba(163, 42, 46, 1);
  font-size: 35px;
}
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}
.wrapper div {
  color: #fff;
}
#one {
  width: 20%;
}
#two {
  flex: 1;
  background: lightblue;
  text-align: right;
}
#two a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Gotham', sans-serif;
  font-size: 17px;
  color: #000;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
#two ul {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
}
#two li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px 0 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="one">
    <p class="w-text-1">Strategy</p>
  </div>
  <div id="two">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Visioning</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Strategic Analysis</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Strategy Formulation</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Business Model Innovation</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Financial Modeling</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your css for `#two`, to add in the `20%` of `#one`, to make 100%:

```
#two {
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 76%; /* this is completing the width with the 4% padding */
    padding-top: 17px;
    padding-right: 4%;
}
```

Comment: @MrLister No, that won't work, the OP wants full width, not auto width floated right

Comment: The forced line break before the fourth list item already ensures that not the whole width of #two will be used anyway. No matter how wide you make it.

Answer (score 0):

Hi please modify these

Lets make the parent element as 100% and make the children div as 50% each

```
.wrapper { 
   width : 100%;
}

#one {
  float:left; 
  width:50%;
}
```

width to 46% because we have given padding right as 4% so (46+4 = 50)

```
#two { 
  float: right;
  width: 46%; 
  padding-top: 17px;
  padding-right: 4%;
}
```

:)

Answer (score 0):

```
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

This will remove padding as part of the width of all elements. Don't use '*' as a selector as it's quite heavy on the DOM.

```
#two {
  width: 80%;
}
```

Because 20% + 80% = 100%

```
#two li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

This will add a width and a height to the li's